# Presentation for image of homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider rings $E$ and $F$ each with a finite presentation. Consider a homomorphism $\eta : E \rightarrow F$, where $\eta$ is defined on the generators of $E$. How can we find a presentation for the image of $\eta$ if $\eta$ is not surjective?

Comment: Do you have generators for $\ker \eta$?

Comment: No. The motivation here is I want to show that $\eta$ is an injection. If I knew what the kernel was then it would be easy.

Comment: There is no reason why $\eta$ would be an injection. In fact, it does not seem obvious to me that $\ker \eta$ should be finitely generated.

Comment: What I meant was that I have a specific case where I want to show $\eta$ is an injection. I thought this approach might help.